# How to Get Data from database in Codeigniter..?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have A Problem to Fetch Data From Database in Codeigniter ..
its gives an Error
This is My View:-

```
       <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row->Country_id;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->country_name;?></td>  
        </tr>
```

Model:-

```
     //data is retrive from this query  
     $query = $this->db->get('country');  
     return $query->result_array();
```

Controller:-

```
     //load the database  
     $this->load->database();  
     //load the model  
     $this->load->model('select');  
     //load the method of model  
     $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
     //return the data in view  
     $this->load->view('select_view', $data);
```

Comment: Your passing `$h`, where is `$row` coming from?

Comment: DataBase:-CREATE TABLE country  
(  
   Country_id int,  
   country_name varchar(255)  
);

Comment: $row comes from foreach loop

Comment: Time to hit the docs, it sounds like your not out the gate yet: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: Add more of your code to make sure we can help you. Add the full select function of your model. Add the foreach loop in your view

Comment: And most importantly: What is the exact error that you run into?

Comment: Use result and not result array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller

```
 $this->load->database();  
 //load the model  
 $this->load->model('select');  
 //load the method of model  
 $data['h']=$this->select->get_data();  //You can change the function name
 //return the data in view  
 $this->load->view('select_view', $data);
```

Your Model

```
$query = $this->db->get('country');
return $query->result_array();
```

Your view

Use foreach loop to show your data

```
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row['Country_id'];?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row['country_name'];?></td>  
 </tr>
```

Comment: As shown in the comments of the question, he already uses a foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

I Solve My Problem By This minor Change.
View:-

```
 <?php foreach($h as $row):?>
    <tr>  
       <td><?php echo $row->Country_id;?></td>  
       <td><?php echo $row->country_name;?></td>  
    </tr>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model:-

```
  //data is retrive from this query  
 $query = $this->db->get('country');  
 return $query->result();
```

Controller:-

```
 $this->load->database();  
 //load the model  
 $this->load->model('select');  
 //load the method of model  
 $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
 //return the data in view  
 $this->load->view('select_view', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

**Controller**

```
public function getdata(){
$condition_array = array();
                $data = '*';
                $result = $this->common->select_data_by_condition('Tablename', $condition_array, $data, $sortby = '', $orderby = 'ASC', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array());
}
print_r($result);
```

**Model**

```
function select_data_by_condition($tablename, $condition_array = array(), $data = '*', $sortby = '', $orderby = '', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array()) {

        $this->db->select($data);
        $this->db->from($tablename);

        //if join_str array is not empty then implement the join query
        if (!empty($join_str)) {
            foreach ($join_str as $join) {
                if (!isset($join['join_type'])) {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id'], $join['join_type']);
                }
            }
        }

        //condition array pass to where condition
        $this->db->where($condition_array);


        //Setting Limit for Paging
        if ($limit != '' && $offset == 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        } else if ($limit != '' && $offset != 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }

        //order by query
        if ($sortby != '' && $orderby != '') {
            $this->db->order_by($sortby, $orderby);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        //if limit is empty then returns total count
        if ($limit == '') {
            $query->num_rows();
        }
        //if limit is not empty then return result array
        log_message('debug', 'fetching data result:' . $this->db->last_query());
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: `//if limit is empty then returns total count
        if ($limit == '') {
            $query->num_rows();
        }` This does nothing. Also, in what aspect does this code solve a problem in relation to the question?

Comment: Huh? How is this related?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your items like `$row->country_name` you need to use `result()` not `result_array()`.